# performance of HTML map with lots of text

Tags: javascript, html, performance, svg, canvas

I'm trying to create a simple floor plan HTML page that has a few geometric elements (rectangles, circles) in various transformations and mostly, lots of small text labels.
I've tested a few approaches for this so far:

1. Having everything in a single SVG that the user can pan across and zoom in and out of. This works fine but the animation of the zoom is quite sluggish and has a significant delay. Looking at the profiler, that time spent is dominated by "Layout"
2. Same as 1, a single SVG but replace the many `<text>` elements with images which are created on initialization by rendering into an invisible canvas and using `toDataURL()`. This made zooming animation very snappy but now the initialization time of the page increased x10 from 500ms to 5 seconds.
3. Same as 2, but generate the images offline on the server. This reduced the initialization time but increased the bandwidth and overall load time on a mobile device with spotty network (where this is going to be used) is still in the order of a few seconds.

Is there no way to win this? What I'm looking for is some solution that will have the low load time of 1. (500ms) and the zoom snappiness of 2.

Comment: Perhaps you can load data progressively, only load those shapes and labels that are visible in the viewport of the user.

Comment: Or generate the canvas labels on the client only when the user scrolls them into view